# Multiple Inserts vs. Bulk Insert From Disk for hydrating SQL Server reference tables

Tags: sql-server

When doing database design, I often use reference/support tables, as we all do. Each time I start up a new project there are inevitably tables which:

- Have a predefined set of values.
- Will never change, and likely never encounter new records (or very infrequently).

A perfect example of this might be a `Country` table,.

```
create table Country
(
  CountryKey  int         not null identity
 ,CountryName varchar(64) not null
 ,IsoNumber   int         not null
 ,Iso3        varchar(8)  not null
 ,constraint pk_country primary key clustered (CountryKey)
);
```

I have used  a number of different approaches to "hydrate" these kinds of tables, primarily:

- A hydration SQL script with insert statements.

  - `insert into Country (CountryName, IsoNumber ...) values ('Canada', ...)`
- A hydration SQL script, reading from disk, using `bulk insert`.

  - `bulk insert MyDatabase.dbo.Country from ...`
- And in extreme cases a programmatic script (f#, python).

My preferred approach is the first if all tables only contain a few records. If the tables are beyond this limit, I typically like a script reading from CSV files. I elect to use CSV in that it's both compact and human-readable.

How is everyone else handling this situation?

> I realize that this is a somewhat opinionated question. But I figured it was worth asking, since it will inevitably have **concrete answers** with technical rationale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Separate Files

Keep `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT`, `GRANT` scripts separately.  Data MIGHT change "per project" (eg 'Oui' vs 'YES').  Additionally, this seems to be a common design for most projects I've seen/worked on.

## INSERT vs Other

Bulk operations (f#,python,CSV) are faster than multiple single-row `INSERT` statements.

I would definitely use `INSERT` for a few rows.  The "cutoff point" between `INSERT` and Code/CSV would be a personal decision.

## Usage of Code

I would only consider using code (f#,python) if and only if the data is Calculated based on input parameter(s).  (eg a `DAY_DIMENSION` table that loads *n* days at a time)

## CSV Scripts

For sizable data, you'd want to use a CSV Script for speed

The script that loads the CSV (or other format) file should use the Filename as a parameter. All utilities (eg SQL*Loader) do this; you just need to filter the parameter up to the Shell Script level.
This allows you to load a different (project specific/updated revision) file at-will.

Make sure you note if globbing (eg `LoadMyData.sh data_0[1-3]*.csv`) is allowed.

## Dumps

One of the easiest ways to port tables is to use Dumps (as Dave has suggested). (eg Oracle's `expdp`/`impdp`)

You should still have the DDL statements available so that you can recreate the tables (and dump) as necessary.